# How to write correct left Join of two tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to join two tables, first table primary key data type is number, and second table primary key data type is VARCHAR2(30 BYTE). How to join both tables.

I tried this code but second tables all values are null. why is that?

```
SELECT a.act_phone_no,a.act_actdevice,a.bi_account_id, a.packag_start_date, c.identification_number, 
FROM ACTIVATIONS_POP a
left JOIN customer c
on TO_CHAR(a.act_phone_no) = c.msisdn_voice
```

first table

```
act_phone_no   bi_account_id
23434             45345
34245             43556
```

Second table

```
msisdn_voice    identification_number
23434              321113
34245              6547657
```

Comment: Try the other way `a.act_phone_no = TO_NUMBER(c.msisdn_voice)`

Comment: Sounds like msisdn_voice contains invisible characters. You can check this with `DUMP`, e.g. select msisdn_voice, dump(msisdn_voice) from customer where msisdn_voice like '%23434%';

Comment: Why don't you show us a full test case?  Your SELECT references column names that do not appear in either (unidentified) table that you purport to show.  A test case includes actual ddl to create necessary tables, and actual INSERT to populate them with minimal test data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using Oracle ?

Please check the below demo

```
SELECT a.act_phone_no, a.bi_account_id, c.identification_number
FROM ACTIVATIONS_POP a
left JOIN customer c
on TO_CHAR(a.act_phone_no) = c.msisdn_voice;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87197/1)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you didn't tell us everything. Query *works*, if correctly written, on such a sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- Sample data
  3  activations_pop (act_phone_no, bi_account_id) as
  4    (select 23434, 45345 from dual union all
  5     select 34245, 43556 from dual
  6    ),
  7  customer (msisdn_voice, identification_number) as
  8    (select '23434', 321113  from dual union all
  9     select '34245', 6547657 from dual
 10    )
 11  -- query works OK
 12  select a.act_phone_no,
 13         a.bi_account_id,
 14         c.identification_number
 15  from activations_pop a join customer c on to_char(a.act_phone_no) = c.msisdn_voice;

ACT_PHONE_NO BI_ACCOUNT_ID IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER
------------ ------------- ---------------------
       23434         45345                321113
       34245         43556               6547657

SQL>
```

What could be wrong? Who knows. If you got *some* result but columns from the `CUSTOMER` table are empty (`NULL`?), then they really might be `NULL`, or you didn't manage to join rows on those columns (left/right padding with spaces?). Does joining on e.g.

```
on to_char(a.act_phone_no) = trim(c.msisdn_voice)
```

or

```
on a.act_phone_no = to_number(c.msisdn_voice)
```

help?

Consider posting proper test case (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements).